R Highcharts Annotation associated with two locations
I would like to create a plot with R and Highcharter and place an annotation on it that is connected to two points (and not just one point).
That ist what I try:
# Laden der Bibliothek
library(highcharter)

# Laden der Titanic-Daten aus dem 'datasets'-Paket
data <- datasets::Titanic

# Umstrukturierung der Daten für den Plot
data_long <- as.data.frame(as.table(data))
colnames(data_long) <- c("Class", "Sex", "Age", "Survived", "Count")
data_long$Count <- as.numeric(data_long$Count)

# Filtern der Daten für Erwachsene
data_long <- subset(data_long, Age == "Adult")

# Erstellen des gestapelten Balkendiagramms
hchart(data_long, "column", hcaes(x = Sex, y = Count, group = interaction(Survived, Class)), stack = TRUE) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "percent"))%>%
hc_annotations(list(
  labels = list(
    list(
      point = list(x = 0.5, y = 60, xAxis = 0, yAxis = 0), # Zwischen den Bars
      text = "Differenz: 12%",
      style = list(fontSize = "11px") # Optional: Anpassen der Schriftgröße
    ) 
  )
))

The result:
result
The expected result:
expected result

This is one (hacky) option which use shape="connector" to draw the connecting lines and using allowOverlap=TRUE connects to the second point using a transparent label:
library(highcharter)

# Erstellen des gestapelten Balkendiagramms
hchart(data_long, "column", hcaes(
  x = Sex, y = Count,
  group = interaction(Survived, Class)
), stack = TRUE) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "percent")) |>
  hc_annotations(
    list(
      labelOptions = list(
        shape = "connector",
        allowOverlap = TRUE
      ),
      labels = list(
        list(
          point = list(
            x = 1,
            y = 35,
            xAxis = 0, yAxis = 0
          ),
          text = "Differenz: 12%",
          style = list(fontSize = "11px"),
          x = -130,
          y = -120
        ),
        list(
          point = list(
            x = 0,
            y = 65,
            xAxis = 0, yAxis = 0
          ),
          text = "Differenz: 12%",
          style = list(fontSize = "11px", color = "transparent"),
          x = 130,
          y = -15
        )
      )
    )
  )


